# Find specific line that match certain array of keyword by using line.contains()

Tags: java, string, readline

I have some problem. Here, I want to use string[] inside the line.contains(), previously I try one code, if  I put line.contains(String), it do read the keywords, but I just can enter one keyword at a time. So, I try to group the keyword in an array but the main problem is line.contains() cannot read String[].

Here is the code :-

```
package components;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class matchWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        String[] errorType = {"uuid=A5H50AV_promo1, for domain=null", "Start node"};
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

        int count = 0;
        //now read the file line by line
        for (int i = 0; i < errorType.length; i++) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                //it doesn't read the errorType[i] as i can see that the count=0
                if (line.contains(errorType[i])) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Error Description :" + line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Error Type : " + errorType + "\nCount : " + count);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Someone please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add sample input & output.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the for and while loops:

```
   //now read the file line by line
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine(); //also be sure to put this outside the for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < errorType.length; i++) {
            if (line.contains(errorType[i])) {
                count++;
                if (count == 1) { //also this 
                    System.out.println("Error Description :" + line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem was that the outer loop was interating over the error messages to check, and the inner loop was iterating over the lines fo the file.

So in the first loop, the program would check **all lines** in the file against the first element in the array, going all the way to the end of the file. From the next loop onwards, the scanner was already at the **end of the file**, so it couldn't read any more - so the inner loop would not even get executed once...

Also, this seems smelly:

```
if (line.contains(errorType[i])) {
    count++;
    if (count == 1) { //also this 
        System.out.println("Error Description :" + line);
    }
}
```

The `count == 1` condition will only be true **once**. Only the first error message gets printed. If you need all error messages (as it would seem logical), you should probably handle this part this way:

```
if (line.contains(errorType[i])) {
    count++;
    System.out.println("Error number: " + count + " Error Description :" + line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following

```
        int count = 0;         
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();                      
            if (Arrays.asList(errorType).contains(line)) {
                count++;
                if (count == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Error Description :" + line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Instead of

```
        for (int i = 0; i < errorType.length; i++) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            //it doesn't read the errorType[i] as i can see that the count=0
            if (line.contains(errorType[i])) {
                count++;
                if (count == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Error Description :" + line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: a line contains is different from a list contains. Although your code looks good, it does something different than the author seems to want. It suposes that the line is litterally contained in the errortypes.